# SQL difference between cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

**Using MS SQL 2012**,

I have table, I need to find the difference against a certain price, this new column will be the price adjustment when i import into a CMS.

[SQL Fiddle Schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12758)

**DISCLAIMER:** not sure if fiddle is working never used sql fiddle before, nut the schema and some data is there.

**Pseudo:**
Each price that is NOT like 'xCarcass' on column st_style, then work out the difference between it and xCarcass based on the same pd_ref

**Explanation**
So basically each PD_Code has several prices depending on what st_style there is.  In my cms I want to import these prices, xCarcass is used as my base price and i want all other st_styles to show the price difference rather than the full price. (difference absed on its base price i.e xCarcass price).

**So far:**
I knew i would need to create a cte query for this but im real novice with CTEs.

```
WITH cte as
(SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Pricing].[pd_code] ORDER BY [pd_ref]) row,
[pd_code]
  ,[pd_ref]
  ,[pg_groupref]
  ,[pr_price]
  ,[pg_group]
  ,[st_styleref]
  ,[st_style]
FROM [Pricing])

SELECT a.[pd_code]
  ,a.[pd_ref]
  ,a.[pg_groupref]
  ,a.[pg_group]
  ,a.[st_styleref]
  ,a.[st_style],
   a.pr_price - ISNULL(b.pr_price,0)
FROM 
      cte a
      LEFT JOIN cte b
      on a.[pd_code] = b.[pd_code]
      and a.row = b.row+1
```

As you can see this doesnt work at all, as i have not specified a condition,  i think its completly wrong, but I'm pretty sure I need to use a CTE query in this problem.

Can anyone work out the proper way to perform this query to the problem described? If you require any further clarification, please ask.

**Expected OutPUT**

```
**pd_code | pd_ref | pg_groupref | pg_group | st_styleref | st_style | Price    | (no col name)**

  DG 100  | 72166  | 1336        | xCarcass | 3484        | xCarcass | 500 | 0 

  DG 100  | 72166  | 1337        | grp 1    | 3480        | stlye 3  | 550 | 50

  DG 100  | 72166  | 1338        | grp 2    | 3488        | style 7  | 700 | 200
```

**NOTE** (note sure how to edit this info as a nice table)

**Further clarification**

To help clairify, each pd_code has about 111 rows of different styles, 1 of which is called 'xCarcass', all styles have a rpice, i need a new column on the end that basically caluclates the difference between its price and that of the specific row of 'xCarcass' for each pd_code

Comment: Try using `LEAD()` function

Comment: can you show some sample input and the expected output here? it is not totally clear what you need

Comment: expected output would be useful

Comment: added expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `max` window function to get the price of xcarcass row for each pd_code and use it for subtraction on all the other non xcarcass row's for that pd_code.

```
select p.*
,pr_price - coalesce(max(case when st_style like '%xcarcass%' then pr_price end) over(partition by pd_code) ,0) val_diff
from pricing p
```

Comment: brilliant, I thought i was on the right track using a cte but didnt reliaze i could do a complex condition on the column of a select clause.  many thanks, ill double check the results and get back

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql-server-2012, then there is an analytical function available to achieve this which is `LEAD()`. Below is the query which you can make use of

```
SELECT 
[pd_code]
  ,[pd_ref]
  ,[pg_groupref]
  ,[pr_price] - ISNULL(LEAD(pr_price) OVER(ORDER BY pd_ref), 0)
  ,[pg_group]
  ,[st_styleref]
  ,[st_style]
FROM [Pricing]
```